# Prove Convergence of Iterative Least Square Algorithm in space of Basis Functions

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, approximation, least-squares, contraction-mapping

I have the following problem where I have already established convergence in the general case. I would like to show the convergence in a lower-dimensional space spanned by basis functions.

**General problem**

Consider the following recursion and establish that the algorithm will converge to a unique solution $ v^* \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ from any initial guess $v_0$ and small enough time step $\Delta t$ as $ t \to + \infty$:

$$
v_{t+\Delta t} \left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) = G(v_{t} \left ( \mathbf{x} \right )), \quad \mathbf{x} \in \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}
$$

where $\Omega$ is a compact set, $v_{t} \left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) = \left [ v \left ( x^{(1)} \right ) , \cdots , v \left ( x^{(n)}  \right ) \right ]' $ is the $n$-dimensional vector of images of each matrix lines $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ by $v_{t}$ and G is a continuously-differentiable non-linear map $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$.

For more context, the $x^{(i)}$'s are the $n$ points used for the discrization of a $k$-dimensional state-space and, $v$ is the value function that I need to solve, and $G$ results from the discretization of some PDE $ F \left ( \mathbf{x} , \mathbf{v} , \triangledown \mathbf{v} , \triangledown^2 \mathbf{v} \right )$ using a FD scheme. I want to solve for the solution to an HJB equation using a time-marching algorithm, which is a fixed-point of the above equation. You can abstract from the $\mathbf{x}$'s for now (I come back to them later):

$$
\mathbf{\mathbf{v}}_{t+\Delta t}  = G \left ( \mathbf{v}_{t} \right ), \quad \mathbf{v}_t \in \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$

*Proof:* In my setup, I can show that the Jacobian is of the following form

$$
\triangledown_v G(\mathbf{v}) = \left [ (1+\rho \Delta t )\mathbb{I}_n  - A \Delta t  \right ]^{-1} 
$$

where $\rho>0$, $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, and it is zero column-sum and has only non-negative off-diagonal elements, *i.e.*

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{ij} = 0  , \forall i \quad  \text{ and  } \quad \left| a_{ij} \right| = a_{ij} , \forall i \neq j  
$$

Let $B = (1+\rho \Delta t )\mathbb{I}_n  - A \Delta t  $. By Gershgorin circle theorem, one can show that all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $B$ are bounded below by $1+\rho \Delta t$ as they are contained in the circles of center $1+\rho \Delta t - \Delta t a_{ii}$ and of radius $R_i = \Delta t |a_{ii} | $. Therefore, $ \mathbb{I}_n  - A \frac{\Delta t}{1+\rho \Delta t}  $ is invertible and

$$ \left\|  \triangledown_v G(\mathbf{v})  \right\|_2 \simeq  \left\| \left (  (1+\rho \Delta t )\mathbb{I}_n  - A \Delta t \right )^{-1} \right\| _2 + o \left ( \Delta t^2 \right )
 < 1 + o \left ( \Delta t^2 \right ) $$

Hence the algorithm converges quadratically to the solution $\mathbf{v}^*$ provided that $\Delta t$ is small enough.

**Modified problem**

Typically in the above problem, $n$ is very large because it corresponds to the grid points used for the discretization of $\Omega_{dense}$.

I now want to reduce the dimensionality of this problem by approximating the values $\left \{ v_{i} \right \}_1^n$ using $M$ basis functions $\left\{ \phi_1(.), \cdots  , \phi_m(.) \right\}$ mapping $\Omega_{dense}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ (I chose local polynomials in my case). Typically, $M << n$. Let $\tilde{V}$ be the space spanned by my basis functions.

$$
\tilde{V} = \left\{  \tilde{v} \in \mathbb{R} : \tilde{v} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \phi_m\left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) w_m = \Phi \left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) \cdot \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m \text{ and } \mathbf{x} \in \Omega_{dense} \right\}
$$

Now, the problem rewrites

$$
\widetilde{\mathbf{v}}_{t+\Delta t} = G(\tilde{\mathbf{v}}_t), \quad \widetilde{\mathbf{v}}_t \in  \widetilde{V}
$$

where G is the same non-linear map. This problem can be reduced to finding a fixed-point $\mathbf{w}^*$ of the $\mathbf{w}_t$ coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^M$:

$$ 
\mathbf{w}_{t+\Delta t} = \tilde{G}(\mathbf{w}_t), \quad \mathbf{w}_t \in \mathbb{R}^m
$$

I want to use the same dataset of $\left \{ v(x_i), 1 \leq i \leq n \right \}$ therefore the above problem becomes overdetermined. I again can show that the Jacobian has a convenient expression:

$$
 \triangledown_w \tilde{G} \left ( \mathbf{w} \right ) =    \tilde{B} ^{\dagger} \Phi
$$

where $\tilde{B} = B \Phi =  \left [ (1+\rho \Delta t )\mathbb{I}_n  - A \Delta t  \right ] \Phi$, $\tilde{B} ^{\dagger} = \left [ \tilde{B}' \tilde{B}  \right ]^{-1}\tilde{B}'$ is the pseudo-inverse $\Phi = \left [ \phi_m \left ( x_n \right ) \right ]_{n,m}  \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times M}$ is rectangular. I effectively run a least-square regression at every iteration and project the $n$ values of $v$ onto the space of real coefficients with dimension $M$.

**Question**

I would like to establish that this modified system still converges to a unique solution $w^*$ but despite different attempts, I get stuck on the fact that $\Phi$ is rectangular and complicates the problem.

Would you have any ideas on how to prove this?

---

My attempts led me to noticing the following

- $A$ still is zero column-sum $B$ still has all its eigenvalues bounded below.
- $\tilde{B} = B \Phi$ is full column-rank $M$
- $\tilde{B}$ admits a singular value decomposition that should have singular values closely related to that of B (my guess). See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657137/l2-norm-of-pseudo-inverse-relation-with-minimum-singular-value?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- If the basis $\phi^m (.)$ are orthonormal, one should have that $\phi_m (x) \phi_{m'} (x) = 0 , \forall m \neq m', \forall x$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{M} \phi_m(x) = 1 , \forall x$ (I also didn't prove this). For now, my basis functions are not even orthogonal but I wondered if one could use a change of basis argument.
- $A'A$ is both zero column- and row-sum so its eigenvalues are all $0$

Comment: Note that $\left [   \left ( \left ( 1+\rho \Delta t \right ) \mathbb{I}_n  - A \right ) \Phi  \right ]$ has the same shape as $\Phi$. That being the case, what exactly do you mean when you write $\left [   \left ( \left ( 1+\rho \Delta t \right ) \mathbb{I}_n  - A \right ) \Phi  \right ]^{-1}$? Also, what exactly is $b$ in this context? The lowercase vector implies that it would be a vector, but you say that $\left [ (1+\rho \Delta t )\mathbb{I}_n  - A \Delta t  \right ]^{-1} b$ is an expression for the Jacobian, which seems to imply that $b$ is a square matrix.

Comment: Also, should there be a $\Delta t$ multiplying the $A$ in the expression $[((1 + \rho \Delta t) \mathbb I_n - A)\Phi]$?

Comment: My hunch is that, once you iron out some errors, you'll end up with an expression of the form $\left [  \Phi^\top \left ( \left ( 1+\rho \Delta t \right ) \mathbb{I}_n  - \Delta t A \right ) \Phi  \right ]^{-1}$. If this is the case, then your proof should be fairly easy to generalize.

Comment: Quick correction: in that first comment I meant to say the lowercase **letter** implies that it would be a vector

Comment: Hi Ben! Thanks for spotting the errors, I fixed it and just dropped the $b$ which wasn't relevant to the problem actually (norm less than $1$).

Comment: Yes, the expression for the Jacobian becomes $\left [ \Phi'  \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t) - \Delta t A \right )'   \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t) - \Delta t A \right ) \Phi \right ]^{-1}  \Phi'  \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t) - \Delta t A \right )' $ $ =   \left [(1+\rho \Delta t)^2  \Phi' \Phi - 2(1+\rho \Delta t)(A \Phi+ \Phi' A') + \Phi' A'A\Phi  \right ]^{-1}  \Phi'  \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t) - \Delta t A \right )'  $ but given that  $\Phi$ is rectangular, I don't know what properties to involve to generalize the proof. Any ideas?

Comment: The inverse definitely makes sense now, but I'm not sure how $\tilde G$, which goes from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^m$, could have a rectangular Jacobian

Comment: My bad again (and sorry), I tried to simplify the exposition but I missed a $\Phi$ matrix that makes the Jacobian of $\tilde{G}$ square. Should be OK now. I think there may be a way to prove that the eigenvalues of $\tilde{B}' \tilde{B}$ are bounded below by $(1+\rho \Delta t)^2$ while those of $\tilde{B}' \Phi$ are bounded below by $(1+\rho \Delta t)$. However, it isn't enough for norm of whole expression to be less than 1, and I probably need to use the singular values of $\tilde{B}$ directly

Comment: Your map $\tilde G$ seems to be of the form $\tilde G(\mathbf w) = \Phi^\dagger G(\Phi \mathbf w)$, is that correct?

Comment: Also, in your original Gershgorin circle based argument, shouldn't $a_{ii}$ be multiplied by $\Delta t$?

Comment: $\tilde{G} (w) = \left [ \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t ) + A \Delta t  \right ) \Phi  \right ]^{\dagger} \left ( f (\Phi w_t ) + \Phi w_t  \right )    $ by the $f$ function drops by some FOC argument that is related to the problem and unexposed here. So to your question, yes if $\left [ \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t ) + A \Delta t  \right ) \Phi  \right ]^{\dagger} = \Phi^{\dagger}  \left [ \left ( (1+\rho \Delta t ) + A \Delta t  \right )  \right ]^{-1}  $ but I havent proven it (it may be trivial)

Comment: And yes for the center and radius of the Gershgorin disks although it won't change the lower bound on the eigenvalues

Comment: Unfortunately, $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^{-1}$ does not hold in general. I believe that $B$ would have to have full row-rank in order for that to work, which won't happen here because $\Phi$ is a tall matrix

Comment: Am I correct in saying that your Jacobian should have the form
$$
\nabla_w \tilde G = [((1 + \rho\Delta t)\Bbb I + A \delta t)\Phi]^\dagger(\Bbb I + \nabla_vf)\Phi?
$$

Comment: Yes that is correct. But in the general problem, once the invertibility of $B$ is established, you can take an expansion of $B^{-1}$, and the terms for $f$ and $ \triangledown_v f $ cancel using an FOC condition that is related to the underlying optimization problem. I prefer to stay away from this here as the proof really relies on the $B^{-1}$ having a norm strictly less than 1.

Comment: Never mind, I'm going in an unproductive direction. I think the form for the Jacobian that you give in terms of $B$ is fine, I'm just thrown off by the fact that the Jacobian is being used directly in the formula for $\tilde G$

Comment: Is there a reason that your formula for $\tilde G(\mathbf w)$ has the inverse of the Jacobian of $G$ inside of it? This doesn't seem to correspond to your brief description from your question, i.e. where you apply "least-square regression at every iteration and project the $n$ values of $v$ onto the space of real coefficients with dimension $M$". I would think that your dimensionality reduction scheme should turn into the original problem in the case that $M = n$, but that doesn't seem to be the case for your approach

Comment: The full problem is defined for the $n$ values of $v$ and for which I have guarantee of convergence of the algorithm with $n$ points and to the true solution as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The approximated problem starts from the  *same* full problem but condenses it over $M$ points. I'd like to establish convergence of the $w$ when the system is overdetermined  to minimize the error in the approximation scheme F^h everywhere in the state space (more details [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4756410/optimal-choice-of-regression-points-for-minimizing-the-approximation-error-when))

Comment: So they are identical if $n=M$ and $\phi_m(.)$ are some indicator functions for each grid point $m$.