# Optimal Choice of Regression points for Minimizing the Approximation Error when solving a PDE with Function Approximation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, approximation, numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, approximation-theory

I want to solve a high-dimensional PDE $F(\mathbf{x}, v ,\triangledown v , \triangledown^2 v )$

$$
-\dot{V_{t}}(\mathbf{x})  - A (\triangledown v_t (\mathbf{x})) =  f(\mathbf{x})  , \quad \mathbf{x} \in \Omega 
 \subset \mathbb{R}^{p} 
$$

where $\Omega$ is compact and $v : \mathbb{R}^{p}  \mapsto \mathbb{R}$.

**Standard Approximation Scheme (FD)**

A standard approach to solving this problem is to use a finite difference scheme  $ F^h(h,\mathbf{x_{k}},v(\mathbf{x_{k}}),\left [ v(.) \right ]_k^h) $ over a grid $\mathcal{G}_h = \times_{k=0}^K \left\{ x_{0k}, \ldots , x_{N k} \right\} $ with step parameter $h$, which under some conditions, converge to the correct solution.

This method uses $N^p$ points, hence you quickly face the curse of dimensionality problem, even with $p$ equal to 4 or 5.

If I use a time-marching algorithm to approach the solution (what I'm doing for now as $f$ is highly non-linear), the goal becomes finding a fixed point $v^*$ of the recursion below:

$$
\mathcal{A} \mathbf{v}_{t+\Delta t} = b \left ( \mathbf{v}_t \right ), \quad \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{N^p}
$$

i.e. the discretized algorithm effectively solves a linear system at every iteration and I have already established convergence ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4755986/prove-convergence-of-iterative-least-square-algorithm-in-space-of-basis-function))

**Approximation using a Function Interpolant**

In order to reduce the number of grid points, I want to solve for a function interpolant that is defined using a small set of nodes $\mathcal{S}_m = \left\{ y^{ \left ( i \right )}  \in \mathbb{R}^p ,  1 \leq i \leq M \right\}$ where the $y^{ \left ( i \right )}$'s are the grid points of a sparse grid. Typically, $M << N^p$.

Consider $M$ basis functions $\left\{ \phi_1(.), \cdots  , \phi_m(.) \right\}$ mapping $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$ (I chose local polynomials in my case). $\phi_i(.) $ is the basis function associated with sparse grid node $y^{ \left ( i \right )}$.  Let $\tilde{V}$ be the space spanned by my basis functions.

$$
\tilde{V} = \left\{  \tilde{v} \in \mathbb{R} : \tilde{v} = \sum_{m=1}^{M} \phi_m\left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) w_m = \Phi \left ( \mathbf{x} \right ) \cdot \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^m \text{ and } \mathbf{x} \in \Omega \right\}
$$

Now, the problem rewrites

$$
\mathcal{A} \Phi \mathbf{w}_{t+\Delta t} = b \left ( \mathbf{w}_t \right ), \quad \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^{M}
$$

i.e. I want to find a fixed-point $\mathbf{w}^* \in \mathbb{R}^M$ of the above equation.

What is important is that if I want to use the same dataset of $N^p$ values of $v$ defined at grid points $\mathbf{x}_i $, then the problem becomes overdetermined because the matrix $\Phi$ is rectangular and every iteration solves a least squares regression.

$$
\Phi = \Biggl( \begin{matrix}
\phi_1 (x_{1}) & \cdots & \phi_M (x_{1}) \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\phi_1 (x_{N^p}) & \cdots & \phi_M (x_{N^p}) \\
\end{matrix}\Biggl) \quad \in \mathbb{R}^{N^p \times M} \quad \quad b : \mathbb{R}^{ M} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{N^p}
$$

$$
\mathbf{w}_{t+\Delta t} = \underset{\mathbf{w} \in  \mathbb{R}^{M} }{\min}   \left\| \mathcal{A} \Phi \mathbf{w} -  b \left ( \mathbf{w}_t \right )  \right\|_2
$$

With this scheme, I have the possibility to actually *choose* the points $\left \{ \mathbf{x}^{ \left ( i \right )   }  , 1 \leq i \leq \tilde{N} \right \}$. They may or may not come from the regular grid $\mathcal{G}_h$ of the FD scheme. I just need to ensure that $M \leq \tilde{N}$ and that $\Phi$ has full column rank (no  multi-collinearity).

**Questions**

1. There is a trade-off between performance (number of points) and approximation error over $\Omega$. Is there a theory that could guide the choice of the regression points ?
2. The accuracy of the estimation of the $\mathbf{w}$ coefficients depends on the condition number of the matrix $\Phi$. Is there a way of optimally placing the points  $\mathbf{x}^{ \left ( i \right )}$ over $\Omega$ so as to achieve best accuracy with minimal amount of points ?
3. For a given function approximation scheme $\phi$ and $M$ points, can I find an upper bound or order of magnitude of the approximation error of $v$ I am making ? something like $\sup \int_{\Omega} \left\|  \left ( v^*(x)-\Phi(x)\cdot w^*\right ) \right \| \mathrm{d} x  \leq T(M)$
4. Is using an over-determined system a good idea to start with?