# L2 Norm of Pseudo-Inverse Relation with Minimum Singular Value formal source?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, online-resources, pseudoinverse

Given a full column rank matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. The left pseudo-inverse is $A_{\text{left}}^{-1}=(A^\top A)^{-1}A^{\top}$. Then we have the following relationship
$$\|A_{\text{left}}^{-1}\|_2=\frac{1}{\sigma_{\text{min}(A)}}$$.

I have seen this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657137/l2-norm-of-pseudo-inverse-relation-with-minimum-singular-value) , and there is also an [online problem set](https://www.rt.isy.liu.se/student/graduate/Verhaegen/exercise1.pdf) that contains this problem. My question is: Where does this problem come from? I want to know whether it is from a certain book so that I can cite it in a proper way.

Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Hint: $\lVert X \rVert_2^2 = \sigma^2_\max(X) = \lambda_\max (X X^T)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I just wonder if you know where this come from? I need a source of it to cite in my research paper actually

Comment: This is a very standard result. You can find many resources if you search for "singular values" and "(induced) matrix norms".